# Search filter with multiple values on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Basically I need code that returns a true/false of whether or not all of the search strings are found within 3 fields of a Javascript object (to filter a list view).

This code will execute for each element of a list view to determine whether or not it should stay in the list or be filtered out. Each element contains 3 fields (PONUM, DESCRIPTION, and VENDOR). A user can type one or more search terms in a textbox and I want to make sure that every word typed appears in at least one of the fields.

Sample list of elements:

```
[ROW] | PONUM | DESCRIPTION | VENDOR
1     | PO10  | ABC         | ABCCOMPANY
2     | PO11  | DEF         | ABCCOMPANY
3     | PO12  | GHI         | XYZCOMPANY
4     | PO20  | JKL         | XYZCOMPANY
```

If I type the following filter: `PO1 ABC`

I should see rows 1 and 2 but NOT 3
("PO1" AND "ABC" were found in at least one of the 3 columns for rows 1 and 2, for row 3, "PO1" was found, but "ABC" was not in any column)

If I type: `PO1 XYZ`, I should only see row 3.
If I type: `PO2 ABC`, I should see nothing.

As for the code itself, I have an array of search terms (I take the text entered and split it on spaces), called `searchTerms`. The values for each of the fields are accessed by using item.Attributes.[fieldname].content, such as `item.Attributes.PONUM.content` etc.

I tried the following *recursive* method that in theory should have worked, but I'm getting a "maximum stack call" error in the browser.

```
function search(searchTerms,x,item) {
    if(x < 0) { 
        return true;
    }
    if(item.Attribute.PONUM.content.indexOf(searchTerms[x] != -1) {
        return search(searchTerms,x--);
    }
    if(item.Attribute.DESCRIPTION.content.indexOf(searchTerms[x] != -1) {
        return search(searchTerms,x--);
    }
    if(item.Attribute.VENDOR.content.indexOf(searchTers[x]) != -1) {
        return search(searchTerms,x--)
    }
    return false;
}

//Function is called like this:
return search(searchTerms,searchTerms.length-1,item)
```

Basically it walks (backwards) through the search terms. If it finds it in one of the fields, it calls search again, with the next search term (x--). If it doesn't find it, it returns false right away (that item will now be filtered). If it continues to find each of the search terms in one of the fields, it will eventually hit -1 (end of the search terms) and return true because it found all the search terms in one of the fields.

Or at least that's what I *think* my function should be doing ;)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK, for starters, `indexOf(searchTerms[x] != -1)` is probably not doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Another thing, you probably wanted to *decrement* `x` in these lines: `search(searchTerms,x++)`.

Comment: BTW. your approach is interesting, but I honestly believe, that a conventional loop (or Timo's functional approach) will cause less head scratches in the future.

Comment: Sorry the x++ was actually x--, I just copied the wrong code. Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach may make for a cleaner solution here:

```
function search(terms, item) {
    return terms.every(function(term) {
        return ['PONUM', 'DESCRIPTION', 'VENDOR'].some(function(attribute) {
            return item.Attributes[attribute].indexOf(term) !== -1;
        });
    });
}
```

More info on [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

---

ES6 features like arrow functions make for an even nicer syntax:

```
const search = (terms, item) =>
    terms.every(term =>
        ['PONUM', 'DESCRIPTION', 'VENDOR']
            .some(attribute => item.Attributes[attribute].includes(term));
    );
```

Comment: if the search terms were `PO` and `10` it will return a match even if it shouldn't.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Those terms would match the first row, which should be fine, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just use *map* and *reduce* functions (from ***lodash***). Before you must *join* all required fields in one.

```
filteredList: function () {
    let query = _.split(_.trim(this.input), ' ')
    return this.list.filter(function (comp) {
      let row = _.join([comp.ponum, comp.description,  comp.vendor], ' ')
      let result = _.map(query, function (part) {
        if (part === '') return true
        return row.indexOf(part) !== -1
      })
      return _.reduce(result, function (x, y) {
        return x & y
      }, true)
    })
  }
```

Here is [how it work](https://codepen.io/SanSan-/pen/mBrQYQ) codepen

> Time complexity = O(n)
>
> Memory complexity = O(n)

---

**Explanation:**

We got our search query: `"PO1 XYZ"`

After *split* it into array we got

```
let query = split("PO1 XYZ") => ['PO1', 'XYZ']
```

### Let's *count* our list with *filter* and *join* all required filed in one.

First pass:

```
join(["PO10", "ABC", "ABCCOMPANY"], " ") => "PO10 ABC ABCCOMPANY"
```

Let's *map* our query array to boolean array like that

```
['PO1', 'XYZ'] => ["PO10 ABC ABCCOMPANY".indexOf('PO1') => true, "PO10 ABC ABCCOMPANY".indexOf('XYZ') => false] => [true, false]
```

and *reduce* result array of boolean by *conjunction* with ***true*** (*neutral value for conjunction*)

```
true & true & false => ((true & true) & false) => false
```

### As result "PO10 ABC ABCCOMPANY" isn't matching with query "PO1 XYZ". We don't show it.

Third pass:

```
join(["PO12", "GHI", "XYZCOMPANY"], " ") => "PO12 GHI XYZCOMPANY"
```

Let's *map* our query array to boolean array like that

```
['PO1', 'XYZ'] => ["PO12 GHI XYZCOMPANY".indexOf('PO1') => true, "PO12 GHI XYZCOMPANY".indexOf('XYZ') => true] => [true, true]
```

and *reduce* result array of boolean by *conjunction* with ***true*** (*neutral value for conjunction*)

```
true & true & true => ((true & true) & true) => true
```

### As result "PO12 GHI XYZCOMPANY" is matching with query "PO1 XYZ". We show it.